# How can I center Wave Trend Oscillator over 0-line? (Pine Script V4)

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am displaying Wave Trend and RSI together on my indicator and I would really like to position the Wave Trend Oscillator at line 50 instead of line 0, how can I do that?

[RSI and Wave Trend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7b18.png)

I don't know much pinescript so I need help

Comment: You need to share your code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Add +50 to the Wave Trend Oscillator